# C#: matlab.Feval command does not work

Tags: c#, matlab

I get this error message:
 **Error    1   No overload for method 'Feval' takes 2 arguments**

My matlab function which i call in c# has only one input argument (txt-File)! If i use the command "Feval" it says i need 2 arguments... But which 2arguments? I have only one input parameter... Thank you

The problem:

```
 //matlab.Feval("test_2",input,res); -> Trouble


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the MATLAB instance 
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

            // Change to the directory where the function is located 
            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\z003dukj\Documents\MATLAB\test_2");

            string[] input = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\z003dukj\Documents\MATLAB\aaaa.txt");

            // Define the output 
            object result = null;

            // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
            matlab.Feval("test_2",input);

            // Display result 
            object[] res = result as object[];

            Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(res[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no uppercase -> Error 1 'MLApp.MLApp' does not contain a definition for 'feval' and no extension method 'feval' accepting a first argument of type 'MLApp.MLApp' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second input to [`Feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/com.feval.html) should be the expected number of output arguments of your custom function. In your case, that appears to be zero, so your call to `Feval` should be

```
matlab.Feval("test_2", 0, input);
```